# Где должен храниться файл c расширением properties?

Tags: java

Где должен храниться файл c расширением properties?

Выдает ошибку на строке:

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("in");
```

> `Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name in, locale be_BY
>         at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
>         at Runner.main(Runner.java:9)`

Answer (score 2):

Файл может храниться где угодно при условии, что путь к файлу включен в classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Или в директории с проектом или указывайте путь полностью.

Comment: Попробуйте указать имя полностью `ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("in.properties");`